# Networking two linux machinies with/without switch

Tags: networking, server, ssh, network-manager

I'm trying to build a network between my desktop and Rberry pi3. I have both crossed cable and a switch which I can use for this project.

How and which files should I configure on my Desktop to be able to connect both to internet (via eth0) and to Rberry pi (via eth1).
I would appreciate for both with crossed cable solution and with switch.

## My desktop:

- eth0 = 10.0.3.98 connected to my router   #internet
- eth1 (USB ethernet adapter) = 10.0.2.98   #Privat LAN

## Raspberry pi:

- eth0 = 10.0.2.95 will connect to my desktop and ssh to it or vice versa.

Comment: Read `man ip-route`.

Comment: I've been doing research and trying different methods since yesterday but couldn't get it work. Writing here was my last option. I read the "ip-route"  but didn't understand how should I do the configurations.

Comment: If you're doing a direct cable to the Pi, you can theoretically use a link-local IP, which requires basically no configuration. Food for thought.